# Setting Sentry-attributes based on spring profile

Tags: spring, sentry

Is there any way to set different values for sentry attributes based on the current Spring profile?

The current attributes are located in the sentry.properties file...

Unfortunately naming it like the application.properties method (application-profilename.properties) does not work. Because the changes in a sentry-profilename.properties file aren't recognised.

**So ideal would be:**

```
sentry.properties (base information)
sentry-dev.properties (environment attribute = dev)
sentry-prod.properties (environment attribute = prod)
```

Comment: Their is an overriding mechanism in Spring property loader, look around this.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any good resource to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, we defined the systems variable `SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT` to `dev` or `prod` (based on the current deployment pipeline).

So this solved our issue and we got the wanted result in the sentry.io overview!

Answer (score 0):

"You can override the location of the properties file by using either the sentry.properties.file Java System Property or the SENTRY_PROPERTIES_FILE System Environment Variable." this is from "https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#configuration"